Why does Java not allow you to pass List<MyImpl> to a method that expects List<MyInterface>?
public interface MyInterface {
}

public class MyImpl implements MyInterface {
}

public class MyThing {
    public static void doThing(List<MyInterface> something)
    {

    }

}

public class DoThing {
    public static void doThing()
    {
        List<MyImpl> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        myList.add(new MyImpl());
        MyThing.doThing(myList); // not ok!

        ArrayList<MyInterface> myList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        myList.add(new MyImpl());
        MyThing.doThing(myList2); // Totally fine
    }
}

This seems confusing to me? The type of elements in the collection implement the interface, so why won't DoThing::doThing() take it?
I came across this because I was just doing something where I was building a specific collection, and then wanted to pass that collection to a method that expected a collection with the interface. It seems annoying that I basically have to worry about building the collection in a specific way even though the type in the collection implements the interface!
I was just curious as to why this is the case, or if I'm being dumb somehow.

Try public static void doThing(List<? extends MyInterface> something) or public static <T extends MyInterface> void doThing(List<T> something). PECS. Producer Extends, Consumer Super.

Other relevant questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super

The doThing() method could try to add a MyOtherImpl object (that also implements MyInterface) to the list that you pass as argument. This would be fine if you pass it a List<MyInterface> but must not be allowed if you pass it a List<MyImpl> (because that list must contain only MyImpl instances)

Try to put the statement something.add(new MyInterface() {}); to doThing. As you can see, doThing could add elements to the list which implement MyInterface but are not instances of of MyImpl. Obviously a no-go for the caller when it provided a List<MyImpl>. If you prevent adding such elements, e.g. by changing MyThing.doThing(myList); to MyThing.doThing(Collections.unmodifiableList(myList));, it’ll work.

Thanks for the fast answers everyone! This was super useful and directed me to the information I couldn't find.
Thanks to @ElliottFrisch for solving the problem in this specific instance.
